# Why is lazy loading nested relation for each item in collection end up loading same values as last item's relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I lazy load a relation for every item in the collection based on some condition, all items end up having the same relation loaded.
That loaded relation for all items is the last item's relation.

I tried setting custom attribute like

```
$single->owner->parent->filenames = Model::where('id', $id);
```

but it doesn't work either. Here is my code

```
$index->transform(function($single) use (&$i){

            if($single->content_type === 'type1') {

                $single->owner->parent->load('fileNames');

            } else if($single->content_type === 'type2') {

                //     $single->owner->parent->file_names = Model::where('id', $single->owner->id);

                $single->owner->parent->load(['fileNames' => function($q) use ($single) {
                    $q->where('file_names.id', $single->owner->id);
                }]);

            }

            return $single;
        });
```

In case of 'type2', I want $single->owner->parent->file_names to be having one entry with an id that is given in where clause

But What I get is all items in the collection ends up having the same value of  owner->parent->file_names attribute as the collection's last item's owner->parent->file_names attribute.

Comment: 'use (&$i)' has no significance. Its just typo

Comment: Does items in collection share single relationship object for each one? If yes, then how to load unique relation object for every item in collection?

Comment: Its $single->owner->parent->fileNames everywhere, not $single->parent->fileNames. Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was eager loading 'parent' and it seems eloquent uses same relation object for all items in collection if relation is eager loaded before. Kind of what I understood or guessed.

I solved it by manually setting relation attribute and cloning the 'parent' object for each item in collection. Not very elegant but works for me now.

Please let me know if you have better solution using laravel or eloquent lazy eager loading methods

```
$parentIds = $index->whereIn('content_type', ['type1', 'type2'])->load('owner')->pluck('owner.parent_id')->unique()->toArray();

$parents = collect([]);

foreach($parentIds as $singleParentId) {
    $parent = Parent::where('id',$singleParentId)->with('tags', 'category', 'titles')->withCount('allComments')->get()[0];
    $parents->put($singleParentId, $parent);
}


$index->transform(function($single) use ($parents) {
    if($single->content_type === 'type1' || $single->content_type === 'type2') {

        $single->owner->setAttribute('parent', clone $parents->get($single->owner->parent_id));

    }

    return $single;
});


$index->transform(function($single) {

    if($single->content_type === 'type1') {

        $fileNames = FileNames::where('parent_id', $single->owner->parent->id)->orderByRaw('lower(file_name) ASC')->limit(8)->get();

        $single->owner->parent->setAttribute('file_names', $fileNames);

    } else if($single->content_type === 'type2') {


        $fileNames = FileNames::where('parent_id', $single->owner->parent->id)->where('id', $single->owner->id)->get();

        $single->owner->parent->setAttribute('file_names', $fileNames);

    }

    return $single;
});
```